# How to change from csh to bash as default shell

Tags: shell

I have `csh` as my default shell, as shown by `echo $SHELL`. I want to switch to `bash` as my default shell. I tried the following approaches to no avail:

1. With `chsh` I get:

   ```
   chsh: can only change local entries; use ypchsh instead.
   ```
2. With `ypchsh` I get:

   ```
   ypchsh: yppasswdd not running on NIS master host ("dcsun2").
   ```

I only have `.chsrc` in my home directory and I cannot find any `.profile` files in `/etc`. How can I change my default shell to `bash`?

Comment: It could be useful to know on which type of unix you are.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. Make sure you've got `bash` installed.
2. Learn the location of `bash`:

   ```
   which bash
   ```

   or

   ```
   whereis bash
   ```

   Below, I'll assume the location is `/bin/bash`.

   a) If you have administrative rights, just run as root:

   ```
   usermod -s /bin/bash YOUR_USERNAME
   ```

   (replacing `YOUR_USERNAME` with your user name).

   b) If you don't have adm. rights, you can still just run `bash --login` at login, by putting the below line **at the end** of your `.cshrc` or `.profile` (in your home directory) :

   ```
   setenv SHELL /bin/bash
   exec /bin/bash --login
   ```

Comment: 2b. Check if `bash` is enumerated in `/etc/shells` with correct path.

Comment: @manatwork That would be relevant for **2a**, not 2b. And only useful in a strange/broken system setup for determining why the solution did not work.

Comment: Yes, actually my intention was to write something like "2a.b".

Comment: 1. SHELL=/bin/bash gives a command not found error. 2. Your solution gives me a bash shell as the prompt. But it does not change my login shell. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Here is what I did to resolve this. 1. exec /bin/bash --login in the .cshrc file 2. set SHELL=/bin/bash and then export SHELL in the /etc/profile file. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I meant the first line to be `export SHELL=/bin/bash`. Actually there's a better way than that - see update.

Comment: You don't have to do the which/whereis separately. For example, ``SHELL=`which bash` `which bash` YOUR_USERNAME``

Comment: exec /bin/bash without --login works for me

Comment: `exec /bin/bash --login` does not seem to be reading `.bashrc`

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Because it is not supposed to do so. This seems to be a very common misconception - some distributions even ship default `.bash_login`, `.profile` or similar files which remedy this. But that is quite far from the original subject. You may ask a separate question.

Comment: This seems to break non-interactive uses, like `scp`. You need `if ($?prompt) then; exec /bin/bash --login; endif`

Comment: WARNING: After adding `exec /bin/bash`, scp stopped working for me.

Answer (score 13):

Contact your system administrator. He's set things up wrong. If *you* are your system administrator then *you've* set things up wrong.

The error message looks pretty straight forward. You don't have `yppasswd` running on dcsun2. It should be.

But doing a quick google search comes up with [this result](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/forums/showthread.php/15660-Quick-HOWTO-Configuring-NIS-yppasswdd-error) which indicates that you'll get this error if `yppasswd` is running on both the client and the server. In this case turn it off on the client.

---

If you're stuck with csh as your login shell, you can still make it invoke bash when you log in. Put the following commands in your `~/.login` (see also [Changing the default shell without chsh or administrator priviledges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26556/changing-the-default-shell-without-chsh-or-administrator-priviledges)):

```
sleep 2
if (-x /usr/local/bin/bash) then
  exec /usr/local/bin/bash -l
endif
```

Replace `/usr/local/bin/bash` by the proper path if necessary. If everything works, remove `sleep 2` (which puts a delay during which you can press `Ctrl+C` to drop to a csh prompt, in case something goes wrong).