# Changing the default shell without chsh or administrator privileges

Tags: shell, zsh, login, exec

I saw the following snippet in this thread: [How to change from csh to bash as default shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/how-to-change-from-csh-to-bash-as-default-shell)

```
sleep 2
if (-x /usr/local/bin/bash) then
  exec /bin/sh -c '. ~/.profile; exec /usr/local/bin/bash'
endif
```

My understanding is that if you place this snippet in `~/.login` it will invoke `bash` when you login.

I have a similar situation where I would like to use a similar snippet to invoke a  version of `zsh` that is different from the default one with which I log in. Part of the reason why I am going through this trouble is because I can't choose my desired version of `zsh` in the options allowed in `chsh`, and I don't have administrator privileges.

With this:

- How would I change the snippet above to do this when switching between different versions of zsh?
- Why are two `exec` commands needed in the snippet above? What do they do? Also, why does the snippet above use `sh` **and** `bash` (the user is supposed to login with `csh`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to execute zsh instead of bash, just replace `/usr/local/bin/bash` by the path to the `zsh` executable. Note that this snippet is specific to csh; if your login shell is not (t)csh, this code in `~/.login` won't do anything for you.

As for why the snippet was written that way, you'd have to ask the person who wrote it. *[Checks who that was.]* Oh. Well, if you just do `exec /usr/local/bin/bash` then you won't be starting a login shell, so your `.profile` won't be executed. But this could be resolved in a simpler way by executing `/usr/local/bin/bash --login`.

Now, if your login shell is not csh, you'll want a different snippet around `exec`. In Bourne-style shells, including zsh:

```
if [ -x ~/bin/zsh ]; then exec ~/bin/zsh; fi
```

Make that `exec ~/bin/zsh -l` if you want the new instance of zsh to read your `~/.zprofile`. Note that if you do that, the snippet above must be in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`; if your login shell is zsh, don't put the snippet in your `.zprofile`, or else make very sure that the new instance of zsh isn't going to call that `exec` again.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. I wrote the following on my `.zprofile`: `if [[ $ZSH_VERSION != 4.3.14 ]]; then                                                                                                      
exec /n/sw/zsh-4.3.14/bin/zsh --login                                                                                                      
fi` and that seems to work!