# Making zsh default shell without root access

Tags: bash, zsh, login, profile

I am using my school's computers and would like to use `zsh` instead of `bash`. I'd like to make it the default shell, but I cannot run a command such as `$ chsh -s $(which zsh)` because I don't have admin privileges.

Is there a way I can put something in my `.bashrc` or something that automatically calls `zsh` when it opens as a workaround?

To clarify, `zsh` is already installed.

Comment: Yes, just add `zsh` on the `.bashrc` file. Logout and login and done!

Comment: Sorry about that. But to finish the question, I just put `zsh` on the first line?

Comment: Placing zsh in .bashrc would make it always execute even when `bash` is called explicitly. Better place it in `.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: You can set zsh as your default shell in the terminal preferences (create a new profile).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Create `.bash_profile` in your home directory and add these lines:

```
export SHELL=/bin/zsh
exec /bin/zsh -l
```

Update: `.profile` may work as a general solution when default shell is not bash. I'm not sure if `.profile` may be called by Zsh as well that it could go redundant but we can do it safely with a simple check:

```
export SHELL=/bin/zsh
[ -z "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && exec /bin/zsh -l
```

We can also use `which` to get the dynamic path of `zsh` which relies on the value of `$PATH`:

```
export SHELL=`which zsh`
[ -z "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && exec "$SHELL" -l
```

Comment: What if a Linux admin (root) changes your default shell to something other than bash (but not zsh), for example ksh?  Then `.bash_profile` won't get referenced.  How about put this in `.profile` instead?

Comment: @JoshuaHuber Last test I made, `.profile` didn't work. Also wouldn't `.profile` be called by `Zsh`? It could go redundant. Haven't checked that yet though. (Update: It did work now, not sure what mistake I made before.) Any thoughts about possible drawbacks with using `.profile`?

Comment: @konsolebox  Bash only sources `.profile` if `.bash_profile` doesn't exist (unless you manually source it from `.bash_profile`, of course). Specifically, bash sources the first one of the files [`.bash_profile` > `.bash_login` > `.profile`] it finds. It only looks for `.profile` as a POSIX (Bourne shell) compatibility feature.

Comment: @pyrocrasty Indeed. Just as said in the manual: *"After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable."*

Comment: It worked for to set up a new terminal profile with *Run custom command instead of my shell* changed to `zsh`. `.bash_profile` and `.profile` didn't work (the files were not even executed, Fedora 26 on a university computer).

Comment: What is the purpose of the `-l` flag?

Comment: @MichaelDorst Login mode. Check [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell).

Comment: @lmaooooo Your terminal probably run shells in non-login interactive mode.  This solution was made for login shells only.  I'm not sure if redirecting from non-login shells is a good idea.  Sorry I didn't have an idea about your problem quickly.  This solution is mostly necessary if you're logging in on a remote shell.

Comment: I have added below things in `.bashrc` and restart the terminal worked for me.
```
export SHELL=/bin/zsh
exec /bin/zsh -l
```

Answer (score 16):

Normally you can use `chsh` as a non-root user. But it's occasionally disabled, usually in sites that use some form of networked user database like NIS and LDAP. There might be a `ypchsh` (NIS) or `chsh.ldap` (LDAP) instead.

`chsh` will also usually allow only some *approved* shells, typically the ones listed in `/etc/shells`.

If you can't use `chsh` or its variants at your site, then arrange for your login shell to `exec` your favorite shell, and set the `SHELL` variable to point to your favourite shell.

- If your login shell is `sh`, `dash` or `ksh`: the file you need to edit is `~/.profile`. Beware that this file is read at the beginning of an interactive session as well as by some non-interactive session startup scripts (e.g. for X11 sessions), so you need to take care: only call `exec` (which replaces the current process) when the current shell is interactive. Except for the Bourne shell (the `/bin/sh` of Solaris 10 and before), you can tell that a shell is interactive by the presence of `i` in the option list (`$-`).

  ```
  preferred_shell=
  if [ -x /bin/zsh ]; then
    preferred_shell=/bin/zsh
  fi
  …
  if [ -n "$preferred_shell" ]; then
    case $- in
      *i*) SHELL=$preferred_shell; export SHELL; exec "$preferred_shell";;
    esac
  fi
  ```

  If you want zsh to read your `.zprofile`, pass the `-l` option.
- If your login shell is `bash`, you can proceed as above. Alternatively, you may put these commands in `~/.bash_profile`. Most session startup scripts only read `~/.profile` and not `~/.bash_profile`, but I've seen some that run under bash and read `.bash_profile`, so even there you should be careful not to call `exec` in a non-interactive shell.
- If your login shell is csh or tcsh, see an example in [Changing the default shell without chsh or administrator priviledges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26556/changing-the-default-shell-without-chsh-or-administrator-priviledges)

Comment: chsh will also usually allow only some approved shells, typically the ones listed in /etc/shells
This was the key. I have added zsh with full path here and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't run `chsh` because you don't have admin privileges, *talk to someone who does*.

Most likely you can't use `chsh` as non-root because the system you're using is configured so that `chsh` wouldn't work, for example because the system uses NIS or LDAP rather than just the `/etc/passwd` file. Or perhaps your system's administrator just wants to maintain some control.

The procedure for changing your shell depends on your organization's policies. There may be a local command that does what `chsh` normally does. Or you may need to submit a support ticket requesting a shell change.

Most of the other answers are good, but if your administrators are reasonably responsive you might not want to bother hacking your startup scripts. I'd probably just invoke `zsh -l` manually after logging in until the administrator gets around to updating my account.

Another thing to keep in mind: Sometimes different shells can use the same startup files.  For example, `sh` and `bash` can both execute `$HOME/.profile`, and `csh` and `tcsh` can both execute `$HOME/.login` and `$HOME/.cshrc` (though shell-specific startup files like `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, and `.tcshrc` can override those). If your default shell is `/bin/csh` and you want to use `/bin/tcsh`, updating your `.login` to invoke `/bin/tcsh -l` could create an infinite loop. `zsh` doesn't happen to execute `bash`-specific startup files, so that's not an issue for you.

Most shells set variables that identify which shell you're running (`$BASH_VERSION`, `$tcsh`, `$ZSH_VERSION`). If you're going to write startup code to invoke your preferred shell, it's not a bad idea to enclose it in an `if` so it's executed only if you're not already running that shell. Using the code from [konsolebox's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136424/10454):

```
if [ "${ZSH_VERSION:-unset}" = "unset" ] ; then
    export SHELL=/bin/zsh
    exec /bin/zsh -l
fi
```

(The added complication of checking `"${ZSH_VERSION:-unset}"` rather than just `"$ZSH_VERSION"` allows for the possibility that you've done `set -o unset`, an option that causes a reference to an undefined variable to be an error.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the command, `chsh` is for this very purpose.  Although, I'm not sure that every Linux/Unix distro support that.  Check the man page of `chsh`.

Comment: Some systems also have it as `passwd -s`.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few scenarios.

1. `zsh` is not in `/etc/shells`, and the OP wishes to use it without having to type `zsh` at the command prompt. Possible solutions.

   a) use profile tricks to execute it on login.  This is just as effective as actually changing the shell.

   b) beg the admin to add `zsh` to `/etc/shells` so you can `chsh` to it

   c) beg the admin to change your shell. this is not wise, because it will lose you the ability to `ftp` in. you can only use `ftp` if you have a shell in `/etc/shells`
2. user wishes to escape a restricted shell, most likely `rbash` or `rsh`.

   If `.profile` is editable, the `PATH` can be expanded by editing it. Once `/bin` is in the path, you can then start `bash` from inside `rsh/rbash`, gaining access to the `chsh` command to let you change shells.
   Many commands have shell escapes which can be used to escape a restricted shell and regain access to `chsh`.
3. `chsh` really doesn't work because of some other reason. solution a from possibility 1 is an answer here as well.

Scenario 2 is the only reason to actually change the default shell (it's too restrictive).

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be another method where we can set the custom command to run zsh instead of default bash command [image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried much of the above and had no luck personally. Something to do with how our IT department has things set up. Another option that seems to be working for me is adding this at the end of my bashrc:

```sh
[ -z "$PS1" ] || zsh && exit
```

This should check if the shell is interactive before running `zsh`. Just running `zsh` at the end broke some other things for me, so ymmv.

Answer (score -3):

I do not think the provided answer actually makes `zsh` the default shell. It simple changes the shell to zsh as soon as user logs in to his/her **default shell**. User will still login to its `DEFAULT SHELL` but with this, shell will change to `zsh`

To change the default shell use:

```
usermod -s /path/to/shell username
```

You should be root to do that.

Otherwise the above **workaround** will come handy.

**Added from comment**

```
chsh -s /path/to/zsh  # considered as standard as compared to usermod
```

and it can be invoked by user for him/herself.

Comment: The question pretty clearly states that modifying the system user database (the bit you need root to do in this answer) is not an option.

Comment: `chsh -s /path/to/zsh` is more standard and usually (but not always) doesn't require root access, unlike `usermod` which always does. So your answer has more problems than what the question already states as not working.

Comment: Also, "Is there a way I can put something in my .bashrc or something that automatically calls zsh when it opens as a workaround? ".