# How to use chsh with ldap authentication

Tags: zsh, ldap, chef

How to use zsh as default when starting an ssh session to a remote chef server using LDAP for authentication?

```
tom@chef:~$ chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
Password:
chsh: user 'tom' does not exist in /etc/passwd
```

Zsh is installed on the system.

```
cat /etc/shells
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/bin/dash
/usr/bin/tmux
/usr/bin/screen
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Do you have a `chsh.ldap` command? see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/chsh.ldap.1.html

Comment: @Bodo do I have to run it on the target server I want to switch to zsh on? `chsh.ldap -s /usr/bin/zsh` returns `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: You have to run it on the system that shows the error message in the question. Does `chsh.ldap -h` or `chsh.ldap -l` work? Was the command already available or did you install it just now?

Comment: @Bodo `-h` and `-V` work. `-l` errors out with a `Segmentation fault` aswell. It was installed on the system already.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why this program crashes with a Segmentation fault.

Comment: @Bodo Apparently there is a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=908319) in the nss-pam-ldapd version used on this machine which causes the Segmentation fault

Comment: That means you (or whoever is responsible for the system) should install a newer version of this package, then you can try again.

Comment: @Bodo yeah I think I'll suggest that. If chsh.ldap works after that, I'll notify you on this thread, so you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Did you check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136423/making-zsh-default-shell-without-root-access, this also has some suggestions